# Spring Webflux - lazily initialized in-memory cache

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

can some one help me with a correct pattern for stateful service in SpringWebflux? I have a REST service which communicates with an external API and needs to fetch auth token from that API during the first call and cache it to reuse in all next calls. Currently I'm having a code which works, but concurrent calls cause multiple token requests. Is there a way to handle concurrency?

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExternalTokenRepository {

    private final WebClient webClient;
    
    private Object cachedToken = null;
    
    public Mono<Object> getToken() {
        if (cachedToken != null) {
            return Mono.just(cachedToken);
        } else {
            return webClient.post()
                //...
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    //...
                    return response.bodyToMono(Object.class)
                })
                .doOnNext(token -> cachedToken = token)
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED: Token I receive have some expiration and I need to refresh it after some time. Refresh request should be call only once too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize `Mono` in the constructor and use `cache` operator:

```java
@Service
public class ExternalTokenRepository {
    private final Mono<Object> cachedToken;

    public ExternalTokenRepository(WebClient webClient) {
        this.cachedToken = webClient.post()
                //...
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    //...
                    return response.bodyToMono(Object.class);
                })
                .cache(); // this is the important part
    }

    public Mono<Object> getToken() {
        return cachedToken;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** `cache` operator also supports TTL based on the return value: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly my case is a bit complicated. Token I receive have some expiration and I need to refresh it after some time. Thus, I can't cache this Mono. Depending on an expiration status of the token I should either fetch new token or call refresh request.

Comment: That's a quite important detail which should be part of the question I think.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to an overloaded version of the `cache` operator which might be useful for your use case.